# Application running on server - can't connect to another local database

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I put my MVC4 website on our DEV server running IIS7.5 (.NET4.0 ) and it works fine pointing to either server database or my own local db specified as [Machine Name][Sql Instance]. Application is on application pool running under service account. I made sure that user has that service account added to their SQL Logins and given dbo permission.

When I change in connection string to use other user's machine, and specify [machine name][sql instance] it throws an error.

Error says:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while 
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow 
remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is
not valid)]

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler
'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.]
```

This is connection string:

```
   <add name="ProjectUI" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ViewModels.
   ProjectUI.csdl|res://*/ViewModels. ProjectUI.ssdl|res://*/ViewModels.  
   ProjectUI.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data 
   source=MYMACHINEID\MSSQLSERVER;initial catalog=DBName;integrated 
   security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Things I tried:

- I verified remote connections are enabled on the SQL
- Enabled TCP/IP port
- Added exception to SQL server inbound rules in firewall
- Added service account to local database with dbo permissions

Comment: make sure you have TCP/IP and Named pipes enabled on SQL server

Comment: Are you sure that their instance is named MSSQLSERVER, or is that just a placeholder? And if you add a username/password can you manually connect usually SSMS?

Comment: TCP/IP and Named pipes are enabled on SQL Server @Johnx

Comment: MSSQLSERVER is the instance name of users server. I did try accessing user's database using SSMS and under a service account, in which case it would only connect if I select MACHINEID without the instance name @Charles380. Tried just MACHINEID in connection string, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of settings that worked:

- Enable TCP/IP (and Named Pipes)
- Restart the SQL Server service
- Ensure service account is added to the database and given appropriate permissions
- No firewall settings needed to be changed (no rules were allowed than what was there before)
- Connection string modified to: **data source=UserMachineID** *without* the server instance (since it was the default one MSSQLSERVER)